# JSON access data - strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I am using the OpenWeatherMap API to access weather data with Javascript and AJAX. I am retrieving a JSON data file and would like to access specific variables in the file. When trying to access the "coord" variable, I get a response of "undefined". Strangely, I cannot find the error..

I retrieve this as api_response

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":293.47,"pressure":1004,"humidity":56,"temp_min":291.15,"temp_max":295.37},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":220},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1566062145,"sys":{"type":1,"id":1414,"message":0.0096,"country":"GB","sunrise":1566017321,"sunset":1566069657},"timezone":3600,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

When trying the access the "coord" variable through "api_response.coord" I get a response "undefined".

Can anyone help me?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">  <!–– language check you can perform ––>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1";>                     <!–– necessary to make the website responsive, zoom level to 1 ––>
        <title>Weather API</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Weather API Test">             <!–– this part will be used in SEM, result of content strategy workshops ––>
        <meta name="author" content="Niels"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/maw7hdc.css">                        <!–– adobe font import ––>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="openWeathermap.scss">       <!–– this stylesheet is used for smaller browsers ––>
        <!–– min-width is gebaseerd op de grootte van het browservenster, terwijl min-device-width is gebaseerd op de grootte van het scherm. De breedte van het apparaat wordt door enkele browsers, bijvoorbeeld de oude Android-browser, niet correct gerapporteerd ––>
    </head>

    <body id="body_element">

    <section id="first_section">

        <header id="header_main"></header>

        <div id="api_response"></div>
        <div id="api_specdata"></div>

    </section>

    </body>

    <script src="openWeathermap.js"></script>

    </html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;  
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* avoiding stairstep lines that mess up the UI, always use!! */
}

/* looking for where a particular element is in the code, just remove css code and see what happens and locate the behavioural element */
body {
    font-family: Segoe, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    /* ??px is standard font size from developer tools */        
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    //background-color: $headerColor;
}

#header_main{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;  
    opacity: 0; 
}

#first_section{
    height: 100vh;
}

#api_response{
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}

#api_specdata{
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}
```

Javascript

```
// Set up HTTP request of type xhr
// status code 200 = success 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var api_key = "f77c39703fb6be71e2c5a96e58edc077";

// Setup our listener to process completed requests
request.onload = function () {

    // Process our return data
    // status code between 200 and 300 indicates success
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {

        console.log('success!', request);
        console.log(request.responseText);

        var api_response = request.responseText;
        document.getElementById("api_response").innerHTML = api_response;

        // get specific data out of the JSON response 
        document.getElementById("api_specdata").innerHTML = api_response.coord;

    // other status codes indicate failure 
    // you could set up a broader response handling if there is a use case for it
    } else {

        console.log('The request failed!');
    }

    // This will run either way
    // All three of these are optional, depending on what you're trying to do
    console.log('This always runs...');
};


// Create and send a GET request
// The first argument is the post type (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.)
// The second argument is the endpoint URL
request.open('GET', 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=' + api_key);
request.send();
```

Comment: You need to call `JSON.parse` on the response to convert it to a JS object - otherwise it's just a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the property `coord` from the responseText.

responseText is not a JSON object, rather, its a string representation of the JSON.

You will have to parse that string and then access the `coord` property.

```
    var api_response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

now you can access the property of the api_response JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

[`XMLHttpRequest.responseText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) contains the text return by the response.

If you want to have the parse result you either need to use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the JSON:

```
var api_response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

Or you use [`XMLHttpRequest.response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response) instead, as this will contain the parsed result (under the assumption the server sends the correct content type).

```
var api_response = request.response;
```